# Feature selection with chi square selection after TF-IDF vectorization

Tags: text-classification, feature-selection, tf-idf, chi-squared

I want to know if it is possible to perform feature selection with the chi-square selection method after Term frequency Inverse document frequency (TF-IDF) vectorization of my textual dataset for binary text classification?  If I am not wrong, my features after tfidf should be numbers standardized in the interval [0,1] and the chi-square test for feature selection is typically used with categorical or discrete features.

If not, what is a typical used method to perform feature selection after tfidf vectorization to reduce dimensionality and the numbers of features?